# How does one get better at triangle proofs and paragraph proofs?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question

I have recently started geometry within this school year, and I am currently struggling on proofs, of all things. I can generally study out any kinks I come across, but I am unable to wrap my head around proofs. Is there any way to get better at it, or at least improve upon my proofing skills within a relatively short amount of time?

Comment: Do a lot of exercises that require you to prove statements. Read proofs of similar statements. Adopt what you read into your own proofs. You will see soon that you have started to get the hang of it.

Comment: I feel like this question is one you'll find comforting: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546324/1098096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that you understand the fundamentals of geometry and have understood all the necessary axioms, there is one great way to improve at geometrical proofs, and that is, to read proofs and see how they're written and executed.

For example, and I hope this wouldn't cause a problem, you can check out how I structured my own geometric proof in this problem:

[Find Angle $\alpha$ from the triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538323/find-angle-alpha-from-the-triangle/4538332#4538332)

This along with many other proofs on this site will help you gain a good understanding of how proofs are supposed to be written. Once you have gained a better understanding, the next thing you should do is to repeat the exercises you struggled with before and write their proofs. Rinse and repeat, consistently, and you'll become quite proficient at it. Hope this helps.